# Create SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain with different fftLogSize

Tags: android, superpowered

I'm using the Superpowered library on Android.  I'm using the `SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain` class to do some fft processing but I'm having an odd problem.  First I create a `SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain` with an `fftLogSize` of 11.  After that point if I create more `SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain` objects with the same `fftLogSize` then everything works fine.  But if I create one with a different `fftLogSize` then it doesn't seem to work properly (even a straightforward conversion to frequency then straight back to time domain doesn't work properly).

For example if I do:

```
SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain fft1 = new SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain(11,4);
SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain fft2 = new SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain(11,4);
SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain fft3 = new SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain(13,4);
```

Then `fft1` and `fft2` work fine.  `fft3` does not work - after the conversion to frequency and back to time the signal does not resemble the original signal (sometimes you can hear a garbled version of the original in there, sometimes it's just noise).

The same is true if I only have one object live at a time:

```
SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain fft1 = new SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain(11,4);
delete fft1;
SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain fft2 = new SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain(11,4);
delete fft2;
SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain fft3 = new SuperpoweredFrequencyDomain(13,4);
```

At this point `fft3` won't work correctly.  I also tried `fft3->reset()` but that didn't get it working either.

I get the same problem whether I use polar mode or complex mode in the conversion.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation/bug of the library?  I couldn't see anything in the documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you fft3->advance() with a fixed number, related to the fft log size of 11?

Comment: No, that's not it - I'm just calling fft3->advance() with no arguments

Comment: No, if I do log size 11 followed by 12 then 12 doesn't work.  But if I do log size 13 (or 12) first and 11 second then 12/13 work, but 11 doesn't.  Basically once I've set a log size I can't change it unless I totally kill the Android process.

Comment: I'll email a working example of the problem to your support address.